# rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node -- couldn't find executable

Tags: ros, ros-tutorials, rosrun, ros-groovy, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just installed ros groovy from source on gentoo amd64 and am working through the beginner's tutorials.  I'm on the "Understanding ROS Nodes" tutorial and installed the ros_tutorials metapackage from git using catkin_make in a catkin ws.  I've sourced the correct env variables and `rospack list` shows that ros_tutorials/turtlesim package is installed.  However, the above mentioned command fails, and a listing of all the turtlesim related directories shows no file named as turtlesim_node.  Here is my output:

```
$ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named turtlesim_node below /home/user/ros-groovy-metapackages/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim
$ roscd turtlesim
$ ls *
CMakeLists.txt  mainpage.dox  package.xml

images:
box-turtle.png   electric.png  groovy.png   robot-turtle.png  turtle.png
diamondback.png  fuerte.png    palette.png  sea-turtle.png    turtle.xar

include:
turtlesim

launch:
multisim.launch

msg:
Color.msg  Pose.msg

src:
turtle.cpp  turtle_frame.cpp  turtlesim  turtlesim.cpp

srv:
Kill.srv  SetPen.srv  Spawn.srv  TeleportAbsolute.srv  TeleportRelative.srv

tutorials:
draw_square.cpp  mimic.cpp  teleop_turtle_key.cpp
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59449/rosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node----couldn%27t-find-executable/) by [logicalguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4517/logicalguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4517/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-30**:
does anybody know anything about what may be wrong, either with the wiki or with what I've done??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to compile it before you can run it.  `rosmake turtlesim` will likely do what you need.  Note the tutorials assume you're using prebuilt binaries, so you will have to make some adjustments throughout for running on gentoo.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adiprasojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4677/adiprasojo/) on 2013-04-14**:
I am using pandaboard and have the same problem even after running catkin_make. After searching of this file turtlesim_node inside my ~/catkin_ws working directory, I found it under ~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlesim. So I run the turtlesim_node right there with ./turtlesim_node.

**Comment by [adiprasojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4677/adiprasojo/) on 2013-04-14**:
it works there, but why can't rosrun find it ? btw, the output of echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH shows that it points to my ~/ros_ws working directory. How to correct this, so I could use rosrun easily ?

**Comment by [adiprasojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4677/adiprasojo/) on 2013-04-14**:
found it !. I have to source my devel path too. So I put this source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash at the end of my ~/.bashrc